# Rotation animation of TikZ Picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, animations, animate

I made a simple TikZ picture like this:

[image]

and I would make an animation that rotates the whole image about its z_world axis.

I made this attempt:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}

\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{animate}

\newcounter{angle}
\setcounter{angle}{0}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering

\begin{animateinline}[loop, poster = first, controls]{30}  
\whiledo{\theangle<359}{

\tdplotsetmaincoords{120}{\theangle}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,tdplot_main_coords]

\def\laserPointX{1.5}
\def\laserPointY{0}
\def\laserPointZ{2.5}
\def\moduloQuadro{\laserPointX*\laserPointX+\laserPointY*\laserPointY+\laserPointZ*\laserPointZ}
\def\moduloLaser{sqrt{(\moduloQuadro)}}

% laser plane
\filldraw[red!50, opacity = 0.2] (\laserPointX,\laserPointY,\laserPointZ) -- (0,-0.8,0) -- (0,0.8,0) -- cycle;
\shade [ball color=red] (\laserPointX,\laserPointY,\laserPointZ) circle [radius=0.05cm];

% axis laser
\draw[-latex,line width=3pt,green!70!black,line cap=round] (0,0,0) -- (1.5*\laserPointZ/\moduloLaser,0,-1.5*\laserPointX/\moduloLaser) node[anchor=west]{$y_{laser}$};
\draw[-latex,line width=3pt,green!70!black,line cap=round] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=east]{$x_{laser}$};
\draw[-latex,line width=3pt,green!70!black,line cap=round] (0,0,0) -- (\laserPointX/\moduloLaser*1.5,\laserPointY/\moduloLaser*1.5,\laserPointZ/\moduloLaser*1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z_{laser}$};

% axis world
\draw[-latex,line width=1pt,blue,line cap=round] (0,0,0) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y_{world}$};
\draw[-latex,line width=1pt,blue,line cap=round] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=north]{$x_{world}$};
\draw[-latex,line width=1pt,blue,line cap=round] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z_{world}$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\stepcounter{angle}
\ifthenelse{\theangle<359}{
        \newframe
}{
        \end{animateinline}
}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But I obtained an ugly effect (due to, I think, the TikZ picture that resizes itself every frame) composed by a rotation and a translation.

Does someone know how to achieve a correct rotation?

Comment: @AlexG Sorry, You're right. I edited the question adding the code.

Comment: Your Code is incomplete. Its missing at least a document class and the usepackage for tikz-3dplot

Comment: @MaPePeR Ok, I edited the code again. This time I added the complete code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All frames must share the same, manually inserted bounding box (in 2D screen coordinates) in order to override the automatic, TikZ-computed ones (which may differ from frame to frame).

For parameterized pictures within the `animateinline` environment, the `\multiframe` command is to be preferred over `\whiledo`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[loop, poster = first, controls]{24}
  \multiframe{360}{iAngle=0+1}{
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{120}{\iAngle}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \useasboundingbox[tdplot_screen_coords] (-3,-1.5) rectangle (3,3);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \def\laserPointX{1.5}
    \def\laserPointY{0}
    \def\laserPointZ{2.5}
    \def\moduloQuadro{\laserPointX*\laserPointX+\laserPointY*\laserPointY+\laserPointZ*\laserPointZ}
    \def\moduloLaser{sqrt{(\moduloQuadro)}}

    % laser plane
    \filldraw[red!50, opacity = 0.2] (\laserPointX,\laserPointY,\laserPointZ) -- (0,-0.8,0) -- (0,0.8,0) -- cycle;
    \shade [ball color=red] (\laserPointX,\laserPointY,\laserPointZ) circle [radius=0.05cm];

    % axis laser
    \draw[-latex,line width=3pt,green!70!black,line cap=round] (0,0,0) -- (1.5*\laserPointZ/\moduloLaser,0,-1.5*\laserPointX/\moduloLaser) node[anchor=west]{$y_{laser}$};
    \draw[-latex,line width=3pt,green!70!black,line cap=round] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=east]{$x_{laser}$};
    \draw[-latex,line width=3pt,green!70!black,line cap=round] (0,0,0) -- (\laserPointX/\moduloLaser*1.5,\laserPointY/\moduloLaser*1.5,\laserPointZ/\moduloLaser*1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z_{laser}$};

    % axis world
    \draw[-latex,line width=1pt,blue,line cap=round] (0,0,0) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y_{world}$};
    \draw[-latex,line width=1pt,blue,line cap=round] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=north]{$x_{world}$};
    \draw[-latex,line width=1pt,blue,line cap=round] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z_{world}$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```