# I want to draw the rotation animation of this triangle around the oz axis, and fix the frame (x_0, y_0, z_0)

Tags: 3d, animations, animate, tikz-3dplot

I want to make an animation, to show the rotation of this plate around the axis oz, I used this code

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}% deu angle $\theta_d$ atour de (x) et $\phi_d$ autour de (z)
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=5]

  \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{.5}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\O}{45} % right ascension of ascending node [deg]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\i}{45} % inclination [deg]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\f}{45} % true anomaly [deg]

  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

  \draw [thick,->] (O) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=north east] {$x_0$};
  \draw [thick,->] (O) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west] {$y_0$};
  \draw [thick,->] (O) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south] {$z_0$};
  \fill[black, tdplot_main_coords] (0,0,0) circle (0.5pt)node[medway, anchor=-30]{$O$};

  \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{45}
  \draw [thick,tdplot_rotated_coords,color=violet,->] (O) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=north east] {$z$};
  \draw [thick,tdplot_rotated_coords,color=violet,->] (O) -- (0,1.65,0) node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
  \draw [thick,tdplot_rotated_coords,thick,dashed, color=violet,->] (O) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south] {$y$};

  \draw [tdplot_rotated_coords, fill=yellow!20!gray] (O) -- (1,0,0)--(0,1,0)--cycle; 

  \tdplotdrawarc[thick, tdplot_main_coords, color=red, ->]{(0,0,0)}{\r}{0}{45}{anchor=105}{$\varphi$}
   \tdplotdrawarc[thick, tdplot_main_coords, color=red, ->]{(0,0,0)}{\r}{90}{135}{anchor=180}{$\varphi$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to produce the figure in 3D as shown in the image above, but I have not yet familiarized with the animate package to make latex animations.
[image]
could anyone help me to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it help?: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315839/rotation-animation-of-tikz-picture?rq=1

Comment: in my case the frame (x_0, y_0, z_0) is fixed,  I just want to rotate the x, y around the   (x_0, y_0, z_0)   frame by \varphi angle.

Comment: how can i fix the (x_0, y_0, z_0) frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just following Ignasi's link and making some minor adjustments yields

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[loop, poster = first, controls]{24}
  \multiframe{36}{iAngle=0+10}{
   \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}% deu angle $\theta_d$ atour de (x) et $\phi_d$ autour de (z)
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=5]
\useasboundingbox[tdplot_screen_coords] (-2.3,-0.6) rectangle (2.3,2);
% adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315853/121799
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{.5}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\O}{45} % right ascension of ascending node [deg]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\i}{45} % inclination [deg]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\f}{45} % true anomaly [deg]

  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

  \draw [thick,->] (O) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=north east] {$x_0$};
  \draw [thick,->] (O) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west] {$y_0$};
  \draw [thick,->] (O) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south] {$z_0$};
  \fill[black, tdplot_main_coords] (0,0,0) circle (0.5pt)node[midway, anchor=-30]{$O$};

  \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\iAngle}
  \draw [thick,tdplot_rotated_coords,color=violet,->] (O) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=north east] {$z$};
  \draw [thick,tdplot_rotated_coords,color=violet,->] (O) -- (0,1.65,0) node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
  \draw [thick,tdplot_rotated_coords,thick,dashed, color=violet,->] (O) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south] {$y$};

  \draw [tdplot_rotated_coords, fill=yellow!20!gray] (O) -- (1,0,0)--(0,1,0)--cycle; 
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\iBngle}{\iAngle+90}
  \tdplotdrawarc[thick, tdplot_main_coords, color=red,->]{(0,0,0)}{\r}{0}{\iAngle}{anchor=105}{$\varphi$}
   \tdplotdrawarc[thick, tdplot_main_coords, color=red, ->]{(0,0,0)}{\r}{90}{\iBngle}{anchor=180}{$\varphi$}
\end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thak you @marmot:  the axes x_0 y_0, are fixed I just want to rotate the x, y axes that are connected to the plate

Comment: @moradov Changed.

Comment: i don't know how to fix the (x_0, y_0, z_0) frame??,

Comment: @moradov Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: i want to fix (x_0, y_0 and z_0) axis and make only rotation of the (x, y and z) coordinates around the z axis

Comment: @moradov But this is what this code does.

Comment: this code make all the frame of reference  in rotation, i will make only the frame of reference (x, y, z_0) in rotation, and the frame of reference (x_0, y_0, z_0) must be fix

Comment: @moradov There seems to be a language problem. This code leaves (x_0,y_0,z_0) fixed and rotates only x and y. Either you explain me what you want in clear terms or ask a new question (this question has been marked as a duplicate anyway).